# ヘルプセンターの "質問が クローズ済み または 改善待ち とは？" を改善したい

Tags: 討議, 完了, ヘルプ

少し前に、ネットワークサイト全体で "クローズされた質問" に表示される通知の表示が見直されました。

[New Post Notices are live network-wide - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700)

"通知の表示" が投稿の上部に移動した他、いくつか大きな変更点があります。

- "改善待ち(On Hold)" が無くなった
- クローズに関するメッセージ (投票時やクローズされた場合) が変更

---

この変更に伴い、以下ヘルプページの記述も見直したいと思います。
(後ほど現状の内容を回答に転記します)

[質問が [クローズ済み] または [改善待ち] とは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

**参考:**
[What does it mean if a question is "closed"? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) (英語版の該当ヘルプ、更新済み)

Answer (score 3):

ヘルプページの記述を転記いたしますので、どうぞこちらを直接編集してください。

---

### 質問が [クローズ済み] とは？

#### 質問がクローズされてしまう理由は何ですか？

追加作業が必要な質問や、[このサイトにふさわしくない質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)は、経験のあるコミュニティメンバーによってクローズされることがあります。クローズされた質問は、回答はできませんが再オープンされるように編集することが可能です。質問がクローズされた場合には、個別にクローズ理由が記されたフィードバックが送信されます。

クローズされてから 5 日以内に編集された質問は、再オープンキューに自動的に追加されコミュニティレビューが行われます。信用度の高いユーザーはクローズされた質問への再オープンノミネートができます。十分な数のコミュニティメンバーが同意すると、質問が再オープンされ、回答が受け入れられるようになります。

クローズ/再オープンの権限を持つコミュニティメンバーが質問をクローズする際にはカテゴリがあり、示される引用テキストは以下の通りです。

- **重複** - 重複した質問をクローズする根本的な目的は、すべての回答を一箇所に集めることによって、正しい回答を見つけやすくすることです。詳しくは「[重複とマークされている質問があるのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)」をご覧ください。

> この質問は以前投稿されたことがあり、回答がすでにあります。

- **オフトピック** - 各コミュニティは、そのサイトで許可されるトピックと許可されないトピックを具体的に決定します。トピックの種類については「[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)」をご覧ください。

> この質問は、スタック・オーバーフローではオフトピックのようです。

質問が範囲内に収まるように言い換えることができると思われる場合は、質問を編集するか改善のためにコメントを残してください。

- **より詳細に、または明確にする必要がある** - 問題を解決するために、より多くの情報が必要な場合があります。

> この質問はもっと詳細を説明し、何が問題かをはっきりさせるべきです。

投稿を編集して聞きたいことをより具体的に書き、他のユーザーがコメントで示した懸念事項に必ず対処してください。

- **より焦点を絞る必要がある** - 正しい答えがいくつもある（そしてどれが最も正しいかを判断できない）場合は、おそらく範囲が広すぎます。私たちのフォーマットではより焦点を絞る必要があります。

> この質問は現在、複数の質問をひとつの質問で聞こうとしています。ひとつの質問に絞るべきです。

多くの場合、一つの質問を複数の質問にわけることによって特定の部分に焦点を当てることできるようになり、改善されます。

- **主観性が高い** - 多様な意見に注目するディスカッションは素晴らしいですが、ここでの形式には合いません。

> この質問の場合、どのような答えも個人的な意見や感想になると思われます。事実に基づいた回答ができるような質問にしてください。

意見に基づく質問ではなく、事実に基づく質問になるように焦点を当てて書き直してください。可能であれば質問を編集してください。

#### 質問を[クローズ]できるのは誰ですか？

信用度が 500 点のユーザーは、一日に 24 までのクローズ票を投票できます。質問のクローズ票が 5 票に達すると、`[クローズ済み]`とマークされ回答は受け付けられなくなります。このようなユーザーは同じ方法で質問を再オープンできます。クローズまたは再オープンに投票できるのは一度だけです。(例えば、質問のクローズに投票してその質問がクローズされ、後で再オープンされた場合、もう一度クローズに投票することはできません。)

モデレーターは単一の投票で質問のクローズまたは再オープンができます。

質問の再オープンの詳細は、「[質問のクローズに反対する場合はどうしたらいいですか？どうしたら再オープンできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)」を参照してください。

Comment: "主観性が高い" の引用部分が、"焦点を絞る必要がある" と同じ内容になっており、ヘルプページにも現在この内容で [反映されてしまっています](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) 。

Comment: お教えくださりありがとうございます。2020/04/14の時点ではどうやら"Needs more focus" 及び "Opinion-based" は "This question currently includes multiple questions in one." と記されていたようです。今日の時点では[スペイン語版](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)も日本語版と同じような記載になっているようです。取り急ぎ日本語版に関しましては最新の英語版にあわせたいと思います。